# Designing a network to fit specific amplitude and phase response curves

Tags: passive-networks, active-filter, frequency-response

If we are given a frequency response curve made up of the amplitude (magnitude) and phase (angle) responses, is it possible to design an electronic network with a transfer function identical to the given ones?

I have been thinking about this. An idea which occurred to me was that if we could design a network with constant amplitude and a specific phase response, and also another with a specific amplitude response and zero phase response, the problem would be solved. However, I still haven't found a way around the sub-problems.

Is it possible to design such a network? It could be passive or active.

Comment: Related:[Minimum phase systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_phase)

Comment: Need to be more specific, is it possible questions are a matter of opinion and off topic. You'll get better answers if your specific.

Comment: Or maybe the OP is asking more about a algorithmic methodology for turning a curve into a circuit without trial and error or iterations?

Comment: This problem is very dependent of the bandwidth on which you want to fit the tranfert function : 10% is very different from 3 decades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arbitrary response could require arbitrarily complex circuitry. For example, look at how difficult it is to build a [pink noise filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/322/pink-1-f-pseudo-random-noise-generation).

So the answer to your question is that it is possible to *approximate* a given response to within a certain tolerance, but there's no guarantee that you can produce it exactly.